# the answer in not displaying in desired manner

Tags: html

when i click the calculate button it is not showing the desired result it show same in btnvalue input as previous,if previousally the btnvalue is 2+3 then it show same after clicking calculate button 2+3 but i want the display as 5.

i have tried all function valueOf etc but i didnot get the result, i m writing my code in subline text3 and excuting it in XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>calculater</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-left:40px">
    <h2> PHP Calculator</h2>
    <form method="post" id="formID">

        Enter value: <input type="text" name="btnValue" id='btnValue'> <br> <br> 
        <div style="padding-left: 105px">
            <input type="button" value="9" name="btn1">
            <input type="button" value="8" name="btn2">
            <input type="button" value="7" name="btn3">
            <input type="button" value="+" name="btn4"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="6" name="btn5">
            <input type="button" value="5" name="btn6">
            <input type="button" value="4" name="btn7">
            <input type="button" value="-" name="btn8" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="3" name="btn8">
            <input type="button" value="2" name="btn9">
            <input type="button" value="1" name="btn10">
            <input type="button" value="/" name="btn11" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="0" name="btn12" style="padding- left:33px"> 
            <input type="button" value="." name="btn13" style="padding-right:9px">
            <input type="button" value="x" name="btn14" style="padding left: 7px"><br>
        </div> <br> 
            <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="calculate" name="Calculator">
    </form>     
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
            if($('#btnValue').val()==''){
             $('#btnValue').val($(this).val());
             }else{
             $('#btnValue').val($('#btnValue').val()+($(this).val()));
                }
        });

      $('#Calculate').click(function(){ 


         var cal=$('#btnValue').val( );
         $('#btnValue').val(cal.valueOf() );


     });
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the calculate of 2+3 is 5 not 2+3.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have added the click function to all of your buttons here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
```

This includes your calculate button because it is also a input[type=button] it just has an id of Calculate. So even though you have separated the two functions the ready function takes over and places the value of the calculate button into the text field. Try adding the ready click function to only the buttons you have separated by the div tag and exclude the calculate button. I'm not an expert on jquery so I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

just like what KJEK-Code said your setting a click listener on all button and then trying to set on the calculate button. Second, `cal.valueOf()` won't return the calculated value, it will return the same value as cal.
I have added some fixes based on this link: https://codepen.io/simonja2/pen/QbGYbR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>calculater</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-left:40px">
    <h2> PHP Calculator</h2>
    <form method="post" id="formID">

        Enter value: <input type="text" name="btnValue" id='btnValue'> <br> <br> 
        <div style="padding-left: 105px">
            <input type="button" value="9" name="btn1">
            <input type="button" value="8" name="btn2">
            <input type="button" value="7" name="btn3">
            <input type="button" value="+" name="btn4"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="6" name="btn5">
            <input type="button" value="5" name="btn6">
            <input type="button" value="4" name="btn7">
            <input type="button" value="-" name="btn8" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="3" name="btn8">
            <input type="button" value="2" name="btn9">
            <input type="button" value="1" name="btn10">
            <input type="button" value="/" name="btn11" style="padding-left: 9px"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="0" name="btn12" style="padding- left:33px"> 
            <input type="button" value="." name="btn13" style="padding-right:9px">
            <input type="button" value="x" name="btn14" style="padding left: 7px"><br>
        </div> <br> 
            <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="calculate" name="Calculator">
    </form>     
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
            if($(this).val() == "calculate") {
                var cal=$('#btnValue').val( );
                $('#btnValue').val(calculate(cal));
                console.log(cal.valueOf());

            } else {
                if($('#btnValue').val()==''){
                    $('#btnValue').val($(this).val());
                } else {
                    $('#btnValue').val($('#btnValue').val()+($(this).val()));
                }
            }
        });

        calculate = (value) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                if(isOperator(value[i])) {
                    var o = value[i];
                    var a = value.slice(0, i);
                    var b = value.slice(i+1);
                    return operate(a, b, o);
                } 
            }
            return value;
        }

        isOperator = function(value) {
          return value === '/' || value === '*' || value === '+' || value === '-';
        };

        operate = function(a, b, operation) {
              a = parseFloat(a);
              b = parseFloat(b);
              console.log(a, b, operation);
              if (operation === '+') return a + b;
              if (operation === '-') return a - b;
              if (operation === '*') return a * b;
              if (operation === '/') return a / b;
            }
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your valueable response it works a lot for me.